In Lazarus (FPC), how do I get a pointer to a class or record method?
I need to get the address of a method without using RTTI (sometimes it is not even possible to use it in FPC, mostly with records) so that it can be called later, for example, with RTTI.Invoke.
Here is an example of code that crashes with an error, demonstrating the task:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tm: TMethod;
begin
  tm := TMethod(@Button2.Click); // Access Violation
  Rtti.Invoke(tm.Code, [Button2], ccReg, nil, False, False);
end; 

I also tried an approach that works perfectly in Delphi, but here it crashes on Access Violation too:
  tm.Code := @TButton.Click;
  tm.Data := Button2;
  Rtti.Invoke(tm.Code, [Button2], ccReg, nil); // Access Violation


Through much experimentation, a way out was found:
type
  TClickMethod = procedure (S: Pointer);
var
  p: Pointer;
  tc: TClickMethod;
begin
  p := @TButton.Click;
  tc := TClickMethod(p);
  tc(Button2);
end;


The address of a method is a pointer. So, without using RTTI, if TButton.Click is a TNotifyEvent you can do:
var
  MyClick : TNotifyEvent = nil;
begin
  MyClick := @TButton.Click;     // get its address
  if Assigned(MyClick) do begin
    MyClick(Self);               // call it
  end;  
end;


Unfortunately, this option does not work for me, because I need to call a method on a pointer. I could consider converting a pointer to a method into a delegate, but not directly assigning a method to a delegate.

@Button2.Click in your code is not a TMethod, it is a pointer, correct?

Yeah, that's right.
